# Why does the output of scikit PolynomialFeatures' degree always have one?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-networks, regression

I don't understand why the output of scikit's PolynomialFeatuers' degree always has a one.

Example for degree=2 and [a, b], output is

```
[1, a, b, a^2, b^2, ab]
```

I don't know why it always has a 1.

Comment: What you have above is: `[a^0 * b^0, a^1 * b^0, a^0 * b^1, a^2 * b^0, a^0 * b^2, a^1 * b^1]`

Comment: that 1 is for scale shifts detection. Intuitionally, take that as allowing the math to include outer dimensional forces, which doesn't relate with those variables a or b, or their compositions, which thus are constant.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to add:

- An $n$-th degree univariate polynomial is of the form $\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$, which includes the bias term (i.e. $1=x^0$), even if it can be zero.
- `sklearn` has the option to omit the bias term via `include_bias` option. When set to `False`, you won't see any $1$'s.
- As commented by @sshashank124 you'll have each term's exponent $\leq$ n, if you have $k$ features (i.e. $x_1\dots x_k$), the terms will be of the form: $\prod_{i=1}^k x_i^{n_i}$, where $\sum_{i=1}^k n_i\leq n$.
- This sometimes produces lots of features, specifically: 
  ${{n+k}\choose {n}}$.
  You may also want to use `interaction_only` parameter to only get the interactions (i.e. terms with each feature degree having at most $1$).